# How to invoke my app

Tags: qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I want to invoke my app when user click on a link("www.xyz.com/myapp") from default blackberry browser or somewhere else when this link found and then open my app and perform task according to clicked link.

to achieve this , using this docs [Receiving invocation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/receiving_invocation.html) but still not able to invoke my app.

my Bar-descriptor.xml

```
<invoke-target id = "com.xyz.sampleApp">
    <invoke-target-type>application</invoke-target-type>
    <invoke-target-name>SampleApp</invoke-target-name>
    <icon> <image>sample.png</image> </icon>
    <filter>
        <action>bb.action.VIEW</action>
        <action>bb.action.OPEN</action>
        <mime-type>*</mime-type>
        <property var="uris" value="www.xyz.com/myapp"> </property>
    </filter>
</invoke-target>
```

correct me if i missing something.

Thanks

Ankur

Comment: The link provided is broken. Could you please fix that?

Comment: plz check link again, i have corrected it